# boot fails - PulseAudio

Tags: boot

I'm using Ubuntu for the first time and I'm new in the LINUX world ..

After successfully installing 11.10 as second system besides XP this morning Ubuntu now gets stuck when booting. Right after the GRUB the following screen appears:

- Starting bluetooth             [OK]
- PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions
  saned disablel; edit /etc/default/saned         [OK]

Nothing else happens afterwards, the boot seems to be stuck.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What graphics card do you have and do you get a console if you hit the ctrl-alt-F2 or F3 key combination ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i'm not experienced user too :). Cause of your problem (propably) is that you made your partitions from live cd and your filesystems have owner set to root- from ubuntu live cd instead of root- from instalation. If you are not experienced the best solution is to install ubuntu again, and make partitions again (new partition table) from install ubuntu menu instead of try ubuntu utilities.

PS. I had the same errors, pulse audio have nothing to do with it